# invalid JSON error when clicking button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, json, syntax-error, backend

I am trying to build a simple react page where there are two buttons at the beginning.
The first sends the string 'private' as response when clicked, the second sends 'public' as a response when clicked.
The two strings should come from a mongodb database. It's not done yet, because whenever I click on any of the buttons, I get the same error over and over again.
It's the following:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

This project has a backend server with two GET requests and a react frontend.
You can see them below.
The frontend:

```
function PubPrivBtn() {

async function clickHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'pubBtn') {
        let response = await fetch('/api/public');
        let result = await response.json();
        console.log(result);
    }
    if (e.target.id === 'privBtn') {
        let response = await fetch('/api/private');
        let result = await response.json();
        console.log(result)
    }
}
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)} id='pubBtn'>Public</button>
        <button onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)} id='privBtn'>Private</button>
    </div>
)}export default PubPrivBtn;
```

And the backend:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import props from './porp.model.js'

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auth', async (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Connected!')
    }
    app.get('/api/public', async (req, res) => {
        let pub = await props.where("vis").equals("public")
        console.log(pub);
        res.send(pub)
    })

    app.get('/api/private', async (req, res) => {
        let priv = await props.where("vis").equals("private")
        console.log(priv);
        res.send(priv)
    })
})

app.listen(3001)
```

Plus the schema is `const porp = new mongoose.Schema({ vis: String })`.

I have tried to remake the whole project from zero (not like it was a big deal), but nothing changed, so I have to think the problem is not in my code. Or maybe I'm wrong and it's something obvious.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the two buttons are imported into the main App.js as a `<PubPrivBtn />` component

Comment: Your endpoints are returning html. Are you sure that `/api/public` is what you think? Do you use proxy? Is your frontend served by the server which albo serves the api?

Comment: Ummm. Yes, so I put my proxy to the the wrong package.json. Which means the frontend couldn't communicat with my backend.

Answer (score 0):

My `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",` was in the wrong package.json. (the backend's)
I have replaced it to the frontend and it's now working perfectly fine.
Thanks @Konrad Linkowski! If I hadn't noticed it, your comment would have solved it for sure!